# How to test a jsp param parameter with a string at Struts?

Tags: string, jsp, struts2, param

${param.type} is the variable that I send it from one jsp to included jsp.

I tried that

```
<s:if test="${param.type} == 'message_error'">
```

or

```
<s:if test="'message_error'.equas(${param.type})">
```

Non of them works. How I can check it with struts?

**EDIT 1:**

I send parameter like that:

```
<jsp:include page="/file.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="type" value="message_error"/>
</jsp:include>
```

I will do that struts control at file.jsp

**EDIT 2:**

Here is one step to answer. http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/why-doesnt-the-if-tag-evaluate-params-properly.html parameters are in a Map at Struts2. However my `type` param is not at request I think struts2 cannot see it after request parameters set at first.

Comment: Cn you show the code where you sending the param in the include jsp?

Comment: not too familiar with struts, but you could do `<%= request.getParameter("type") %>` to check if the value is in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also try something like this

```
<s:if test='%{(param.type) == "message_error"}'>
```

Comment: @Kmchi:Any additional params supplied to the included page are not accessible within the rendered page through the <s:property...>  tag or any other way since no valuestack will be created. You can, however, access them in a servlet via the HttpServletRequest object or from a JSP page via a scriptlet.So you have to access these parameters using the plain HTTPServlet request something like <%= request.getParameter("type") %>. Hope this will help you